# Get "400 Login Timeout" with Outlook Web Acces on Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, iis-7.5, outlook-web-app

We have an Exchange 2010 on Windows2008R2 and OWA *was* up and running fine. After recent updates and a reboot, we first had a problem getting the Exchange Management console started. This problem was ultimately solved (something was wrong wit Proxy settings), but it seems that some of our attempts to solve it have broken other stuff.

At least what we are facing now is that OWA gives us "400 Login Timeout" (per `https://localhost/owa`). We have already removed and recreated `owa` and `ecp` virtual directories with no success. We tried to follow whatever google spits out about the subject, but it all seems to be for Exchange 2007 or earlier and therefore at one step or other simply is not applicable to our situation.

- Default Web Site: Has SSL deactivated, Anonymous authentication enabled
- owa virtual directory: SSL activated, Anonynmous and Windows auth, system modules `exppw` and `kerbauth` are added
- In Exchange Management Console, server config, client access, owa, properties: Integrated Windows authentication.

What next?

Comment: have you fixed the proxy settings for all users ? It's possible that OWA is still trying the old, incorrect settings (hint: use `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie`)

Comment: We simply removed the proxy altogether via netsh. I tried yours as well (which should not make a differnce for localhost anyway). No success.